# Angular resource not working in Cordova application

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I have a mobile app built in Angular that is running on Cordova. I am currently testing by emulating using an AVD and also emulating in Chrome.

The application runs smoothly in Chrome and I get no console errors whatsoever, however when I build my android project and then test in the Android emulator I get errors.

Here is the error I get in the Android Monitor:

> 06-20 08:56:01.996 3076-3076/com.app.jwr
>   D/SystemWebChromeClient:
>   file:///android_asset/www/scripts/services/jobs.js: Line 39 : jobs
>   search unsuccessful 06-20 08:56:01.996 3076-3076/com.app.jwr
>   I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(39)] "jobs search unsuccessful", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/scripts/services/jobs.js (39)

Here is the code that it is failing on:

```
    svc.query = function (searchData, start, end) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (typeof start == 'undefined') {
            start = 0;
        }

        if (typeof end == 'undefined') {
            end = 2;
        }

        var JobsRequest = $resource('https://www.jwrecruitment.co.uk/api_jobs_listings.php', {limit: start + ',' + end}, {
            all: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
        });

        JobsRequest.all(searchData, function success(data) {
            if (data[0].response_code == '400') {
                deferred.reject(error);
                console.log("error");
            } else {
                svc.searchQueryData = svc.searchQueryData.concat(data[0].listings);

                deferred.resolve(data[0].listings);
                 console.log("jobs search successful");
                 console.log(searchData);
            }

       // here is where it fails
        }, function err(error) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("jobs search unsuccessful");
            }

            deferred.reject(error);
        });

        return deferred.promise;

    };
```

It seems like it cannot load the resource where I get my data from. The API works fine, tried and tested. Any ideas what's going on here? Why is this only happening when I emulate for android ?

**EDIT**

Here is the JSON for when I `console.log(error)`:

```
{
   "data":"",
   "status":0,
   "config":{
      "method":"GET",
      "transformRequest":[
         null
      ],
      "transformResponse":[
         null
      ],
      "url":"https://www.jwrecruitment.co.uk/api_jobs_listings.php",
      "params":{
         "limit":"0,15"
      },
      "headers":{
         "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"
      },
      "cached":false
   }
}
```

Comment: By `The application runs smoothly in Chrome` you mean in chrome browser on your computer and by `android emulator` you mean running it as android app on emulator? Also the log you posted does not show error, it just says that search was unsuccessful, maybe checking `line 39` of `android_asset/www/scripts/services/jobs.js` can show what is wrong

Comment: @Merka yes that's correct. I am simulating the app in Chrome on my PC as well as on an Android AVD

Comment: I've shown my line 39 above, the part that logs the unsuccessful message.  It's not showing any more detail than that. If I try to console log `error` it shows `"[object Object]"`

Comment: @Merka Any ideas?

Comment: `[object object]` means that it is a json and you can see the content of the error by printing `JSON.stringify(error)`

Comment: @Merka See edit. I've posted the JSON String

Comment: It maybe the search parameter you use that there is no result for them (i.e your search truly should return no result) and as the `"data"` key is empty you see this error log. I don't know how `JobsRequest` work but the problem is in the query. maybe if you monitor the search request which is received from android to your server, you can figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was that the Android Device I was testing on was not connected to the internet so it could not make any external api requests hence why the data was not loading.

You just need to turn on the cellular data from the android device.